# Nhibernate and the case of Auto Updating Entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Best title I could come up with, A little more involved however.

```
// Hit the database once and get all the categories;
IQueryable<Category> qryCategoryList = _repository.Select<Category>();

// get initial parents
var parentCategories = qryCategoryList.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId == null);
foreach (Category parentCategory in parentCategories)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(parentCategory.CategoryName = "This should not happen");
            BuildCategoryList(qryCategoryList, parentCategory.CategoryId);
}
```

This line

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(parentCategory.CategoryName = "This should not happen");
```

performs this

```
UPDATE Categories
SET    ParentCategoryId = NULL /* @p0_0 */,
       CategoryName = '->' /* @p1_0 */,
       CategoryDescription = 'The Fruit Category' /* @p2_0 */,
       Active = 1 /* @p3_0 */,
       DateCreated = '2012-01-20T12:03:41.00' /* @p4_0 */,
       LastUpdated = '2012-01-20T12:03:41.00' /* @p5_0 */
WHERE  CategoryId = 'aa8ca9ba-663c-45c8-950b-159a28e6635d' /* @p6_0 */
```

I am not calling save from my repository not wanting to do an update. How is this possible?

EDIT: Here is the mapping

```
 public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Table("Categories");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.CategoryId).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Column("CategoryId");
        Map(x => x.ParentCategoryId).Column("ParentCategoryId");
        Map(x => x.CategoryName).Column("CategoryName").Not.Nullable().Length(50);
        Map(x => x.CategoryDescription).Column("CategoryDescription").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Active).Column("Active").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DateCreated).Column("DateCreated").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.LastUpdated).Column("LastUpdated").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.PostingsCategories).KeyColumn("CategoryId");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if it is still connected how does that fire off an update?

Comment: More reason to not expose IQueryable LOL

Comment: Sorry Darin, didn't mean to tag MVC 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when something in the mapping or object declaration doesn't quite jive with what's in the database. For example, you might have a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in the database that's nullable but mapped that to a non-nullable Guid on an object. NHibernate selects, sees a Guid.Empty instead of a null, and says "Hey! The object changed! Whelp, reckon I should update it..."

That's just one case of how it can happen. If you post your mapping, we might be able to help you debug it a bit further.

--

Actually, I should have read it a bit further. If this is within the scope of a transaction, NHibernate will auto update any changed entities without needing an explicit call to `SaveOrUpdate()`. It's called autoflush and it's on by default. You'll need to set the `FlushMode` to `Never` if you want to explicitly call `transaction.Commit()` or `session.Flush()`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are getting to. let me know on the mapping, this bothers me not knowing why this is happening :) I fat thumbed some code and got an update Woot!

Comment: Check the FlushMode as described above -- I realized that you were talking about something else entirely. My mistake!

Comment: PS: I have skinny thumbs actually

Comment: Are there any issues with setting flushmode to never, assuming that is a config option? I made great effort to ensure everything is an a transaction.

Comment: Seems like a cool feature actually, no need for call to save or update if in a transaction...

Comment: You'll have to remember to flush the session if you want to commit changes to the database. The intention is that you should be concerned with working with objects in a unit of work, not with managing the database, which is NHibernate's job. If you are temporarily futzing with an entity for display purposes, shuttling that information into a view model object may be more appropriate.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't actually use that code I posted, I was simply testing some stuff in a controller. I am using my IOC container to manage the session, anytime my repository sees an injected SessionManager it auto wraps things in a transaction. I use viewmodels religiously so no worries. So if I set FlushMode to never the transactions will not flush auto anymore?

Comment: still researching where to set the flushmode

Comment: I set  _sessionWrapper.Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never; in my repo the problem went away. I have not tried an update or an insert yet.